# Is it possible to login once for all LiveServerTestCases?

Tags: python, selenium, liveservertestcase

I would like to do something like this:

```
class TestSuite(LiveServerTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        
        # Login User
        self.driver.get(self.live_server_url + '/somesite/login/')
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "username").click()
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "username").send_keys("foo")
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "password").click()
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "password").send_keys("bar")
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "login_button").click()
        # Redirects to home page
    
    @classmethod
    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

    def test_foo(self):
        # Do some clicking with already logged in user from home page

    def test_bar(self):
        # Do some clicking with already logged in user from home page
```

I just feel it is inefficient to call setUp() on every test case.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks...

Answer (score 0):

so move `setUp` from `TestSuite` to `LiveServerTestCase` class

Comment: to improve the answer, please give some explanation as to reason that this fixes the problem

Comment: thank you @olli_kahn for your input. I don't want to mess with third-party modules, but if I understand you correctly, by extending `LiveServerTestCase`; it should work. So would `super()` work in this case? If so, how would I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

I hate to answer my own question... but I got it working thanks to olli_kahn's hint - extending `LiveServerTestCase`.

**Steps:**

- Use `setUpClass`/`tearDownClass` (not `setUp`/`tearDown`)
- Declare `setUpClass`/`tearDownClass` as `@classmethods` (put `@classmethod` first if using more decorators)
- Use `super()` to extend `LiveServerTestCase`
- Use `cls` instead of `self` for `@classmethod`'s to conform to PEP8

**Complete code:**

```
class TestSuite(LiveServerTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(TestSuite, cls).setUpClass()

        cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        
        # Login User
        cls.driver.get(cls.live_server_url + '/somesite/login/')
        cls.driver.find_element(By.ID, "username").click()
        cls.driver.find_element(By.ID, "username").send_keys("foo")
        cls.driver.find_element(By.ID, "password").click()
        cls.driver.find_element(By.ID, "password").send_keys("bar")
        cls.driver.find_element(By.ID, "login_button").click()
        # Redirects to home page
    
    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.driver.quit()
        super(TestSuite, cls).tearDownClass()

    def test_foo(self):
        # Do some clicking with already logged in user from home page

    def test_bar(self):
        # Do some clicking with already logged in user from home page
```